# Run bat file on remote Windows from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, batch-file

I am working on continious integration process and I am using Linux platform for my Jenkins  but now I need to run bat file on remote pc(Windows) to start automation tests processing and send report. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Run another instance of jenkins on that windows and use a remote trigger plugin to trigger the bat.

Comment: the problem is that I've got 19 pc's with Windows on them and I need to run bat file on all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use NodeLabel Parameter Plugin + Parametrized Trigger Plugin to run job on one or several Windows machines.
To start job on all machines in parallel, read [this page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-BuildParameterFactory)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a learning curve to this approach, but I suggest installing Cygwin on the Windows box.  Among Cygwin's many ports of UNIX software is the SSH daemon.  This is a very detailed tutorial for installing sshd on Windows: http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html .  It should be easy to get the SSH client going on Linux.

Then you'd run something like this:
    ssh windowsuser@windowsbox 'c:\path\script.bat'